# How do I install FFMPEG inside Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, discord

I am hosting a Discord music bot on Heroku and it seems it won't play music as the FFMPEG is not found. This is understandable as the FFMPEG is only available within my PC and not on the external cloud. What can I do to install FFMPEG on Heroku?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Self answering as I had this problem and wish to share what I found:**

Heroku supports ffmpeg as a buildpack to your app. Simply open you app settings at `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/[app-name]/settings` and scroll down to Buildpacks, where you should add https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git to it.

Alternatively you can also run the CLI command:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
```

#### Source:

https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest

Comment: Just wanted to add that the docs you link to recommend adding ffmpeg buildpack *at index 1* (i.e. before the ruby buildpack). I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but it may. [Here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest)'s how to add it with index 1: `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
`

Comment: Simply adding the buildpack does not do it for me. I still keep getting the error 'ffprobe' not found