# Rails preview for active storage videos not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I have a pretty standard model where you can upload videos - so far so good.
The video gets uploaded and is also displayed on the show view. Alle seems to be fine....but:

I cannot get a preview fo to work.

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.last.previewable?
--> false
```

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.video?
--> true
```

FFMPEG is installed on the system and in the gem file

```
which ffmpeg   
--> /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'
```

And of course if I run preview directly, I get an error

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.last.preview(resize: "200x200>").processed
--> ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError (ActiveStorage::UnpreviewableError)
```

Previewers is having video included

```
Rails.application.config.active_storage.previewers
--> [ActiveStorage::Previewer::PopplerPDFPreviewer, ActiveStorage::Previewer::MuPDFPreviewer, ActiveStorage::Previewer::VideoPreviewer]
```

I also tried different video formats, but nothing works and I am out of ideas where to look.
Anybody had the same issue?

Comment: I'd try to debug it, can u put a breakpoint inside Rails? here would be a good start https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7702ce8243288265255d042c06fe1ca25e8c02ae/activestorage/lib/active_storage/previewer/video_previewer.rb#L6

Comment: Thanks @Joel_Blum! I cannot say why it is working now, but it works.

Comment: For those finding this later, use this to check if ffmeg is installed properly: 
ActiveStorage::Previewer::VideoPreviewer.ffmpeg_exists?

Answer (score 1):

I had face the same issue, please follow the below step which might help you because it work for me.

1. install the [ffmpeg](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-18-04/)
2. install the [ImageMagick](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-ubuntu)

   attribute :video_preview do |object|
   Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(object.video.preview(resize: "200x200").processed, only_path: true)

end

use this method to check whether is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem of video previews working fine locally but not playing in production. It was simply because I hadn't [installed ffmpeg](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#requirements) in my production environment.

My production environment was heroku, so I simply added the ffmpeg buildpack [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142083/how-do-i-install-ffmpeg-inside-heroku):

```sh
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
```

And then everything worked as expected.