# how do I install ffmpeg for my discord music bot hosted on Heroku

Tags: python-3.x

I added import ffmpeg but the bot returns: An error occurred: Command raised an exception: ClientException: ffmpeg was not found. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install FFMPEG inside Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142083/how-do-i-install-ffmpeg-inside-heroku)